# How to split moment dates into array from time slot?

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

I have a `startDate` and a `endDate` and I want split to array of `startDate` and `endDate`? My splitter is a time slots (not a number as in a pagination).

My typescript code is:

```
startDate: Date;
endDate: Date;
timeSlots: moment.Duration = moment.duration(30, 'minutes');
```

My startDate is `2019-11-02T11:57:00.701Z` and my endDate `2019-11-02T13:31:00.701Z`

I looking for how to slpit an return this result:

```
[
  {startDate: 2019-11-02T11:57:00.701Z, endDate: 2019-11-02T12:26:59.701Z}
  {startDate: 2019-11-02T12:27:00.701Z, endDate: 2019-11-02T12:56:59.701Z}
  {startDate: 2019-11-02T12:57:00.701Z, endDate: 2019-11-02T13:26:59.701Z}
  {startDate: 2019-11-02T13:27:00.701Z, endDate: 2019-11-02T13:31:00.701Z}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`moment-range`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/range/) plugin

```js
window['moment-range'].extendMoment(moment);

const start  = moment('2019-11-02T11:57:00.701Z');
const end    = moment('2019-11-02T13:31:00.701Z');
const range  = moment.range(start, end);

const rangeBy = range.by('minutes', { step: 30 });

const res = Array.from(rangeBy).map(m => ({
  'startTime': m.toISOString(),
  'endTime': m.add(29, 'm').add(59, 's').toISOString()
}))

if(moment(res[res.length -1].endTime).isAfter(end)) {
  res[res.length -1].endTime = end.toISOString();
}

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-range/4.0.1/moment-range.js"></script>
```

Comment: just a small problem on last value (`"endTime": "2019-11-02T13:56:59.701Z"` 
instead of `"endTime": "2019-11-02T13:31:00.701Z"`